# My .htaccess seems to rewrite my URL in GET, instead of maintaining POST

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^.*$ /dispatcher.php
```

My goal is that all requests will go through my dispatcher (as I'm writing myself a pseudo-api, my calls/urls will only be performing actions, not so much retrieving files, data, etc.)

Unfortunately when I call my site through a POST method, my dispatcher tells me (through `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`) that my request is a `GET request`, and all my `POST data` is lost.

What can I do to maintain the request method as `POST`?

**UPDATE**: After checking my requests responses through my browser, the responses are a *404 Page not found*, however, the page is still being correctly displayed. Perhaps the method is being set to GET because it's a 404 redirect? However, still not closer to understanding what would cause this.

Although the 404 response is strange, I know that my .htaccess is working because commenting out the rewrite rule, if i were to call a URL with sub directories pas the base url, it throughs a proper 404 page (with the correct info displayed on the page). With the rewrite rule, however, the response returns with a 404 status, but the page is correctly displayed (except for the request method).

**UPDATE**: As per HamZa's mention, there isn't much more code to be shown; I have a simple form that calls the server with a POST request in order to (try to) trigger a POST method. I think the problem comes from the fact that my htaccess isn't properly rewriting the URL, since calling my base URL will properly call a GET and POST, but if I add additional URL data (such as domain.com//, where module and action are data I pass to the server for calling the right module and function), it will return a 404 response status, still with the correct data.

Comment: This shoulnt remove your POST values. Does the dispatcher redirect the client? cus then you will lose your data there.

Comment: I agree. My first line of code in my dispatcher.php script prints the request method, which returns GET. So because of that, I'm totally confused as to why it shoudn't work.

Comment: @Prusprus I think you should include some code on how you're sending data with the post method. The problem might lie there

Comment: @HamZa I would but there's really nothing to show. At the moment, my sandbox comprises of two files, my .htaccess and my dispatcher. My dispatcher has my code that uses the $_POST variable (which is not usable given that it won't jump into a POST method and a simple form that submits a POST request.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `ErrorDocument 404 default` line on top of your .htaccess like this to disable any custom error handling for 404:

```
ErrorDocument 404 default

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule !^dispatcher\.php$ dispatcher.php [L,NC]
```